# Magento 2 : product collection ASC sort by category

Tags: magento2, category

I want to sort product collection by category ids. I used this below code. What i need to add in this code ?

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
    .....
) {
    .....
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    .....
}


publi function yourfunction()
{
    $catalog_ids = ['14', '61', '62', '63'];
    $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    $productCollection->addCategoryIds()->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $catalog_ids])->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('size_mm', ['eq' => 2650]);
    $productCollection->setOrder('size_mm', 'DESC');
    $productCollection->setOrder('entity_id', 'ASC');
    return $productCollection;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one option as following:

```
        public function yourfunction()
        {
            $catalog_ids = ['14', '61', '62', '63'];
            $sortedCategoryProducts = array();
             foreach($catalog_ids as $catalog_id){
                $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
                $productCollection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => 
                $catalog_id])->addAttributeToSelect('*'); // instead * add only those attributes which you actually need in this change you don't bother that category loads 4 times
                $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('size_mm', ['eq' => 2650]);
                $productCollection->setOrder('size_mm', 'DESC');
                $productCollection->setOrder('entity_id', 'ASC');

           foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
                // here you can also place check to skipp redundant product
                $sortedCategoryProducts[] = $product->getData();
            }
        }

            return $sortedCategoryProducts;
        }
```

Comment: Please verify your code. It returns errors.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Please update your answer. Your if condition return error so. So, after correction i will accept it.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. Actually the condition you removed is required to avoid repetitions  becaus one product can be in different categories, you just need to verify at which key in $sortedCategoryProducts 'entity_id' present. add it in condition.

Comment: Ohh...!! Sorry. Can you please again add that code?